# Is possible to print variables values to Debug without specifying their types?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm printing the value of variables to [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).

There is any 'easier' way to print their value other than manually specifying the `%` `VarTYPE`

Currently doing it this way:

```
WCHAR wsText[255] = L"";
wsprintf(wsText, L"dwExStyle: %??? lpClassName: %??? lpWindowName: %??? ...", dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, ...);
return CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
```

It doesn't necessarily need to be `wsprintf`, being able to print it without needing to manually specify each parameter type would help!

Comment: fmt library or C++20 std::format

Comment: You could use a `wstringstream` and `<<` to construct your string.

Comment: @RetiredNinja something like `std::wstringstream Text; Text << L"dwExStyle:" << dwExStyle; OutputDebugString(Text);`?

Comment: `OutputDebugString(Text.str().c_str());`

Comment: If you have a debugger attached you can dump values without having to write any code. The feature is called *"Trace Point"* in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use string streams, they're more safe then wsprintf too (buffer overruns). And for unknown types you can overload operator <<.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    DWORD dwExStyle{ 0 };
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"dwExtStyle : " << dwExStyle << ", lpClassName: "; // and more....
    OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const your_type& value)
{
    os << value.member; // or something
    return os;
}
```